# How to assert form action attribute url with phpunit and selenium2?

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I have a html form that has this markup.

```
<form id="login-form" action="/post/login">
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <input name="password" type="password">
</form>
```

I want to be able to assert this form action.
I try with this inside the test method, note I extended \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase

```
$form = $this->byId('login-form');
$this->assertEqual('/post/login', $form->attribute('action'));
```

It seems like action always null.

Does anyone know how to test the form action attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `$form->attribute('action')` returns action with base url (`http://localhost/post/login`).

I did not find a way to get action without base and did not find how to get base url. There is my solution:

```
function testForm(){
        $this->url('/test.html');

        $form = $this->byId('login-form');
        $this->assertEquals('/post/login', $this->getRelativeFormAction($form));
    }

    function getRelativeFormAction($form){
        $action = $form->attribute('action');
        $action = str_replace($this->getBaseUrl(), '', $action);
        return $action;
    }

    function getBaseUrl(){
        $urlComponents = parse_url($this->url());
        $url = "{$urlComponents['scheme']}://{$urlComponents['host']}";
        return $url;
    }
```

There is successful [full test](http://pastebin.com/Yu60XGJP) code.